# How to wait for a regular (non async) code (function) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, async-await, full-text-search, processing, loading

I want to search for a word in a big text file that is local (not calling any HTTP or API).
I'm using it with FutureBuilder because **only** the opening of the text file is async (the rest isn't)
but the opening itself is very fast. 
I want to render CircularProgressIndicator, while searching, but it seems that the moment it finishes ***opening*** the file, the  CircularProgressIndicator **stops**, and I have a blank screen for the long searching time.

What can I do to present a loading screen also while doing the **regular** for loop?

What I have is something like this pseudocode:

```
Future<Array> searchData() async{
    results = [];
    someBigTextFile= await getTextFile();
    for(row in someBigTextFile){ // this loop takes a lot of time
        if(row contains this.query) results.add(row);
    }
    return results;
}

Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: searchData(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Array> snapshot){
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
           print("not done yet");
           return CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else {
           return snapshot.data;
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Future call should not be in your build function.  Make the call to your future and use the result in your build function.

```
Future<Array> result = searchData();

Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: result,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Array> snapshot){
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
           print("not done yet");
           return CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else {
           return snapshot.data;
        }
  }
}
```

Where you make the call for result will depend on the structure of the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. With the .then() syntax you can specifically stop sync code from running before a future returns.

```
  Future<Array> searchData() async{
    results = [];
    await getTextFile().then((someBigTextFile){
        for(row in someBigTextFile){ // this loop takes a lot of time
        if(row contains this.query) results.add(row);
    }
    return results;
    });

}
```

Comment: sadly not helping :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use `isolates` to spawn totally new working thread. Something like:

```
Array searchData( String someBigTextFileContents) {
  results = [];
  for(row in someBigTextFile){ // this loop takes a lot of time
    if(row contains this.query) results.add(row);
  }
  return results;
}

Future<Array> searchData() async {
  someBigTextFileContents= await getTextFile();
  return compute( searchData, someBigTextFileContents )
}
```

Better example on here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing